# Read a large file chunk by chunk and append it in a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a large txt file and i want to read it chunk by chunk and store the output in a dictionary.
Sample file look like

```
Id1 Id2
1   3
1   6
1   9
3   1
3   9
6   1
6   3
6   9
9   3
9   6
```

I have tried the following code and it is working, the only issue is that for each iteration, the dictionary is over written, and previous data in dictionary lost

```
import pandas as pd
chunksize = 10 ** 6
for chunk in pd.read_csv('file.txt',delimiter='\t',chunksize=chunksize):    
    d={} 
    for i, j in rel.itertuples(index=False):
        if i not in d.keys():
            d[i]=[j]
        elif j not in d[i] : 
            d[i].append(j)
```

Sample output is as follows

```
{1: [3, 6, 9],
 3: [1, 9],
 6: [1, 3, 9],
 9: [3, 6]}
```

How can i update the dictionary so data of each iteration remained stored in it. We can also create a new dictionary for each iteration or update the existing one. Any clue? Any hint. I will be grateful to you.

Comment: Put `d = {}` outside `for chunk in ...`?

Comment: Thanks, that really work.